# Can't save after running VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

I defined the following VBA macro.

```
Sub sorting()

Dim lngCLC As Long
Dim lngListExist As Long
Dim lngOC As Long
Dim vListArr As Variant

vListArr = Array("X", "Y", "A", "B", "C", "C1", "C2", "C3", "E", "E1", "E2")


lngListExist = Application.GetCustomListNum(vListArr)
If lngListExist > 0 Then
    lngOC = lngListExist + 1
Else
    Application.AddCustomList listArray:=vListArr
    lngCLC = Application.CustomListCount
    lngOC = lngCLC + 1
End If

Range("B2").Sort Key1:=Range("D3"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
    Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=lngOC, _
    MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
If lngListExist = 0 Then Application.DeleteCustomList ListNum:=lngCLC


vListArr = Array("Version 1", "Version 2", "Version 3", "Version 4", "Version 5", "Version 6")
lngListExist = Application.GetCustomListNum(vListArr)
If lngListExist > 0 Then
    lngOC = lngListExist + 1
Else
    Application.AddCustomList listArray:=vListArr
    lngCLC = Application.CustomListCount
    lngOC = lngCLC + 1
End If
Range("B1").Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
    Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=lngOC, _
    MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
If lngListExist = 0 Then Application.DeleteCustomList ListNum:=lngCLC

End Sub
```

However, after running it once in my document I can't save the document anymore.
On attempting to save it crashes.

Before I run this macro is saves just fine, I can keep it open for longer periods of time, but after running it, it crashes the moment I try to save it.

Comment: Probably a file corruption try to save the file as binary xlsb format. If that does not work please provide a [mcve] with example data.

Comment: This contains a minimal reproducible example: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ys5eEU-BfuIq3ms95HWhOg5fSTzIbO_F?usp=sharing

Comment: We tried with xlsb format but it still crashed